# How to import unformatted data into a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have some data in username:email:password format (in a text file), I want to import it into a database. I **do not** want it like this:

```
| username | email           | password |
| admin    | admin@email.com | qwery    |
```

I just need to get it into one column like this:

```
| column: random123               |
| admin:admin@email.com:qwerty |
| user1:user@gmail.com:cats123 |
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you want it in "one column" not all in one row right?

Comment: @markg Yes I meant one column sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used Heidi SQL for this, it has a nice text importer.

http://www.heidisql.com/

and here's a screenshot of the importer, I am pretty sure you'll be able to do what you want, just don't specify a delimitter.

http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=import_textfile

also native in Mysql I think

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html